# How to load bluebird (pulled from NPM) into a Dojo project as an AMD module?

Tags: npm, dojo, bluebird, amd

I am working on a Dojo project which uses a number of NPM packages, one of them being [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) as I need to use Promise in IE. I am looking for the best practice/recommended way to load NPM packages into my project.

The following code is an example illustrating my question:

```js
require([
  'dojo/dom',
  'dojo/request',
  'dojo/domReady!'
], function(dom, request) {

  var message = dom.byId('greeting');
  message.innerHTML = "Getting started";

  var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(true);
    }, 1000);
  });

  var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(true);
    }, 1000);
  });

  var p3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(true);
    }, 1000);
  });

  Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(function() {
    message.innerHTML = "All requests have been completed";
  }, function(error) {
    message.innerHTML = error;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/1.2.2/bluebird.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
<div id="greeting"></div>
```

In order to run the code in IE11, I can load the bluebird library through a `<script>` tag (as shown in the code). However, if I want to manage the library by NPM, I know I can pull it through `npm install`, then either use a `<script>` tag to load the library from the `node_modules` folder in my disk, or reference the library from the `node_modules` folder through `dojoConfig`, but either way I will need to tap into the `node_modules` folder and reference the package there. I am not sure if it is even recommended to do so? For example, CommonJS clearly suggests NOT to do so: http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html:

> Use npm to install Node-only packages/modules into the projects node_modules directory, but do not configure RequireJS to look inside the node_modules directory. Also avoid using relative module IDs to reference modules that are Node-only modules. So, do not do something like require("./node_modules/foo/foo"

If I shouldn't reference the library (or any other NPM package) residing in the `node_modules` folder through its physical path, is there a better way to do so? I am thinking about loading it in Dojo's `require([])` call might be the best place, but I am not exactly sure how to do so.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm install or bower to pull in your project blubird. 
If you thirdparty library is not in AMD which is compatible with dojo you can use:

```
define([...,"path/to/thirdparty.js"], function(){
   // ... your code
});
```

Or use:

```
require([...,"path/to/thirdparty.js"])
```

Notes:

- You do not need to load the library with `<script>`, you can use dojo to load it for you as in snippet above.