# Not able to convert String BST date format to UTC in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo

I have a string like `07-Oct-2019 11:02` in BST format .I have to convert into UTC time in same format which will be `07-Oct-2019 10:02`.

I have tried many ways and tried to find some inbuilt function but nothing worked .
I tried to write a function which will split string and then convert it into date and then UTC but that also did not work .

This is what i have tried

```
var fullDate = "07-Oct-2019 11:02";
            fullDate = fullDate.split(' ');

            var date = fullDate[0].split("-");
            var time = fullDate[1];

            var newDate = date[0] + '-' + date[1] + '-' + date[2] + ' ' + time;
            var k = new Date(newDate);


            alert(d);
```

But this result into current date into IST .

Please help how i can do this .

I am using DOJO framework .

Answer (score 1):

Use [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) to do advanced operations with date and timezone.

Solution:

```js
let date = "07-Oct-2019 11:02"

console.log(
moment.tz(date, "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm", "Europe/London").utc().format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.16/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @SUDARSHAN You can keep a copy of both these libraries and do require similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095312/how-to-load-bluebird-pulled-from-npm-into-a-dojo-project-as-an-amd-module

Answer (score 0):

```js
        var date = "07-Oct-2019 11:02";

        var a = date.split("-");
        var b = a[2].split(" ");
        var dateFormat = a[0] + ' - ' + a[1] + ' - ' + b[0] + ' ' + b[1];
        var convertedDate = new Date(dateFormat);

        weekdayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
        monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

        var dateString = convertedDate.getDate() + "-" + monthNames[convertedDate.getMonth()] + "-" + convertedDate.getFullYear() +" "+ convertedDate.getHours() + ":" + ("00" + convertedDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

        console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: How will it convert to UTC ?